# Spring Cloud Services - Eureka

Tags: angular, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud

I am trying to learn microservices using Spring and Spring Boot, and learning to deploy into cloud platform. I am planning to create an Angular 2 frontend application which communicates with my deployed microservice. Now I just going through Spring cloud services Eureka, Zuul, circuit breakers, etc.

1. When I reading I found that Eureka is using for service registry for finding services each other. Here my doubt is that when I am communicating from my Angular 2 http request, I need to use these service registering?
2. What cloud configuration I need to follow to make a REST API to microservice? I am getting confused how I need to push my sample microservice to cloud, since I am a beginner.

Comment: No. [check this out](https://www.dineshonjava.com/microservices-with-spring-boot/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No...your frontend app should talk to Zuul which is already registered to Eureka and can query it to find the right backend server you need.

I [wrote](https://luizkowalski.net/netflix-oss-a-beginners-guide-pt3/) about it, hope it helps

Comment: Can you share your previous post about the eureka ..And I have one doubt is that, I created my "springbootDemo" as project. You mentioning in that , add two files - application.yml and bootstrap.yml in edge server..You actually meaned that the same project place where the same location of application.properties exist? I did not understood your "In the edge server, create two files in the resources folder: application.yml and bootstrap.yml with the following:" - statement.

Comment: You can start by part 1: https://luizkowalski.net/netflix-oss-a-beginners-guide-pt1/ and the two files, I mean create both files inside `resources` folder in your app. Here is the code: https://github.com/luizkowalski/microservices-netflix-sample/tree/master/edge/src/main/resources

Comment: Yes I got it. I will explore this section. I facing many understanding problem, Now i just started learning on spring boot microservices. I will explore your writings about spring cloud services. Anyway thank you for your response.

Comment: I readed that writing and started to work, but i am getting error like connection refusing. Below I adding my query link, can you guide to findout it?? Link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47096861/creating-an-eureka-server-service-for-spring-boot-microservice.